# How to convert ISO code to localized measure unit in java?

Tags: java, enums, iso, measure

I'm currently trying to convert ISOCODE measure units into the fulltext labels.

For example I'll receive a string such as "LTR" and try to convert it to "Liter". It's in german so I'm also looking for a possibility to do this localized.

Is there a library or so which is already doing this? Is there an enum somewhere, containing all these information?

Otherwise, I guess I'll just have to create one myself.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSR 363](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=363) deals with units of measurement and has been implemented in [UOM](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/) . You can browse [the javadoc](http://unitsofmeasurement.github.io/unit-api/site/apidocs/index.html) to get an idea of what's in there.

There was a project called the [JScience project](http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/unit/package-summary.html), but it doesn't seem to have been updated for some time.

Comment: Yeah I already saw that but it appears they don't include the full labels, just abbreviations. But thanks for your answer